# High side mosfet source voltage does not switch back to ground

Tags: mosfet, buck

I'm trying to make a buck converter with following circuitry:
[image: Buck converter]
I put a PWM in the mosfet driver either with an Arduino nano or an atmega32u4 (same result). The low-side mosfet is not used yet(Gate tied to ground) but is already there since the construct should become 2-quadrant converter in the end.
The exact pieces are:

Mosfets: [IPP50R140CPXKSA1](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/196/Infineon-IPP50R140CP-DS-v02_00-en-1227207.pdf)

Inductor: TLC/10A-102M-00

Capacitor: simple 1 mF elco

Mosfet driver: [TC4432](http://de.farnell.com/microchip/tc4432coa/mosfet-treiber-nicht-invertierend/dp/2709771?ost=TC4432COA&iscrfnonsku=false&ddkey=http%3Ade-DE%2FElement14_Germany%2Fsearch)

I'm driving the High Side Mosfet with a 100kHz frequency and a 0,3 duty cycle (for this test. The duty cycle is variable).

**Problem:**
Here is an oscilloscope picture of two voltages. The yellow curve is the voltage between High-Side mosfet gate and ground. The pink curve is the voltage between the high mosfet source and the ground. 
[image: Scope picture]

Now, what I do not understand is exactly why the High side Source doesn't go directly back on ground. I think it should because of the 10kOhm resistor on the output acting like a pull down. I do recognize (I think) a RC unloading curve but there seems to be an offset too.

I would like the Mosfet to stop conducting as soon as the Gate signal hits ground, but on the other hand I need this high capacitor because of the quite high inductor too (to avoid resonance problems)

I tried highly reducing the output resistor to 150 ohm (as I want to conduct rather high current, the device will have to work with resistances as small as 1 or 2 Ohm eventually), but the result is not stable at all. Here is a picture I made, but it's actually very changing:

[image: picture scope 2]

I looked up several scripts on the buck converter topic, but never found mention of this problem, which leads me to believe it's an uncommon one.

In short, here are my two questions:

Why is the High-side source source voltage behaving this way? What don't I get?
How can I get my mosfet to completely stop leading current as soon as the gate voltage is null?

**Edit:**
For clarification, here is a oscilloscope picture of some things asked about in the comments:
[image: Driver and supply]
The 9 V supply voltage is in blue. 
The driver input is in pink, the driver output in green.

The datasheet of my capacitor is [here](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/315/ABA0000C1022-1144690.pdf). By 1mF for its value, I meant 1000uF

**Edit 2**
Thanks to Trevor_G's comment, I decided to try removing the diode. I began with the Low-Side diode, and the unloading became slower. Then I removed also the other diode.

And here the result with both Diode removed (right picture):
[image: both diode]

Yellow is the gate ground voltage, pink is the Source voltage of the High-side mosfet, blue is the output by the 10k Ohm resistor

So it does seem my problem comes from the mosfet acting as capacitor and then unloading other the diode. What I need is the source voltage going back to ground (at best avoiding any slow unloading process altogether), which leaves me with the question: **how to avoid this capacitor behavior from the mosfet, what could be an help against it?**

Comment: You driver is not high side capable? There is no booster circuit.

Comment: I don't see how this TC4432 can work as a "real" high side driver in your application.

Comment: What is your 9V supply doing during all this?

Comment: @Jeroen3  You're right, it seems I made a stupid mistake when choosing the driver. I'm definitely changing that. Still, I'm not sure this is the cause of my problem because the switching seems to be somehow working though not optimally. (Probably because of the low threshold of the mosfet)

Comment: @Trevor_G The 9V supply gets a slight disturbance when the Mosfet switches on, otherwise seems absolutely all right

Comment: Ya the wrong driver should not effect the turn off. I'd expect the pink trace to fly down to minus a diode drop when the yellow falls. Makes me wonder if the MOSFET is shot or fake. Can you show the drive signal too with gate and with output?

Comment: Did you verify 9V is flat?  What is Dissipation factor (tan delta or ESR) of Cap.  That affects step change in voltage.  Do you know about double layer effects?

Comment: A proper data sheet link for the inductor please and can you clarify that 1 mF means 1000 uF - if yes then a data sheet link for that part too.

Comment: @Trevor_G I already checked both mosfet and even changed them to new ones just to be sure, to no avail. What do you mean by "fake"? I made an edit of the post for the driver input and output

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 9V is flat. (see edit) According to the datasheet, the dissipation effect of the capacitor is 0,02. I do not know about double layer effect at all, going to check this out now, but could it have something to do with my problem?

Comment: "The driver input is in pink, the driver output in pink" - slightly confusing...

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks for pointing out that mistake, that's corrected

Comment: What is cap p/n? check D.F. again. I see higher values.

Comment: Sigh... Re-looking at this, Q2 is acting as a MOSFET capacitor, what you are seeing is that capacitance plus the capacitance of the diode D4 discharging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitance of the mosfet is not the significant issue here. The heart of the issue is the poorly matached reactive components in the output filter. Any parasitic capacitance across the lower mosfet (likely mostly due to the diode or the layout) is going to present some voltage at Q1's source terminal. Not because Q1 is failing to switch off, but just because of the stored energy in the LC circuit and the lack of opportunity to dissipate it.

See the following LTSpice simulation:

[image]

Just 5nF of parasitic capacitance is enough to create the waveform you're seeing:

[image]

If I change the output values to something more suitable: L=3mH, C=60nF and R=150Ohm, but still leave the 5nF of parasitic capacitance, I get something more expected:

[image]

V(n002) is the Q1's gate voltage, V(n004) is Q1's source voltage, V(n005) is the output voltage and I(L1) is the current through the output inductor.

Comment: I tried reducing the output resistor to your value (I don't have more inductors here) and my problem disappeared right away ! (At the cost of a big ringing appearing in my mosfet source voltage. I'll try some more)