# High-side pMOSFET does not switch to ground

Tags: mosfet, switching

This is the schematic in its basic form. It's an nMOSFET that gets driven by a pin of an Atmega328p, this nMOSFET on his turn, drives a big pMOSFET. The source is connected to a voltage regulator (9V6), the drain is connected to the backlight of an RGB screen. The Atmega generates a PWM-signal (100kHz, duty-cycle is variable) so one can change the brightness of the screen.

[image: basic_from]

However, when looking at the drain, I noticed that the OFF-part doens't go to ground and there's lots of ringing.

[image: ringin]

The ringing I could damp by adding a snubber network to the drain of the pMOSFET. But the OFF-part still doesn't go to ground and there is still a sudden peak in voltage that I could not remove. It seems something is pulling the voltage back high.

[image: snubber_network]

[image: snubber_scope]

- How comes that there is still a DC component in the OFF-part of the PWM?
- How can I remove that part so it goes to ground?

The only other question I found, is this one: [High side mosfet source voltage does not switch back to ground](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/352040/high-side-mosfet-source-voltage-does-not-switch-back-to-ground)

So I added a parallel RC network at the output.

[image: with_rc]

Measuring now, it goes down to ground, but there is still a peak present in the signal.

[image: rc_scope]

Can I clean this up further?

Comment: 1. Why high side driving? 2. Why 100 kHz with passive pull-up?

Comment: @winny 1. No reason in particular. You think it would be better to switch on the low side? 2. 100kHz cause otherwise you could hear the switching, and we thought it would be enough. In the first iteration, the switching was a lot slower and the passive pullup was ok but we had the noise. I'm testing now different values and layouts with air soldered through hole components.

Comment: Then I recommend bog standard low side switching. Simpler and cheaper.

Comment: @winny `bog`? Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bog-standard.html

Comment: Assuming your backlight driver is not connected to ground otherwise. Can you "zoom out" and show how it's connected?

Comment: @winny not really, since it's all different blocks. https://i.imgur.com/89UUnUi.png is how it's connected now. `LED+` is connected to `VLED` and `LED-` is connected to `GND`. I can add the nMOSFET between `LED-` and `GND` to do low side switching.

Comment: Can’t tell for sure from that. If you disconnect that connector and measure resistance between LED- and ground, what do you get?

Comment: @winny Ah you mean on the display? So measuring on the ribbon cable? On my board, `LED-` is directly connected to `GND`.

Comment: Yes. If you assume LED- can be disconnected from GND in order to tap in your new driver, but it has some connection elsewhere not seen, your new backlight driver will not work.

Comment: @winny I just measured it, it's `OL` so no direct connection between the two.

Comment: @winny I've changed the board to do low-side switching. Next week I should have my board and I can test it out. In the meantime, you know why it doens't go to ground? I can learn from this and use it next time if I really need to high-side switching.

Comment: Good! You should now be able to cheat :-) Probably due to simplicity in mass production. That way you can have same drivers for different backlights or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

1. When the P-MOSFET is off, it runs no more current into VLED.  It is possible that the input of the LED does not provide a pull-down path, and the drain voltage just keeps floating above ground.  You "fixed" this with the pull-down array that discharges C62 and C63, but such does not seem necessary to operate VLED.
2. The negative peak might be due to the inductor L3.  When the current through L3 collapses, the inductor reacts with a voltage spike of opposite polarity.  Can you try adding a flyback diode across L3 (me not knowing its purpose to begin with)?